# Filter out only matched values from a text file in each line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file "test.txt" with the lines below and also lot bunch of extra stuff after the "version"

```
soainfra_metrics{metric_group="sca_composite",partition="test",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="test123"} map:stats version:1.0
soainfra_metrics{metric_group="sca_composite",partition="gello",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="test234"} map:stats version:1.8
soainfra_metrics{metric_group="sca_composite",partition="bolo",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="3415"} map:stats version:3.1
soainfra_metrics{metric_group="sca_composite",partition="solo",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="hji"} map:stats version:1.1
```

I tried:

```
egrep -r 'partition|is_active|state|is_default|composite'  test.txt
```

It's displaying every line, but I need only specific mentioned fields like this below,ignoring rest of the data/stuff or lines

in a nut shell, i want to display only these fields from a line not the rest

```
partition="test",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="test123"
partition="gello",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="test234"
partition="bolo",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="3415"
partition="solo",is_active="true",state="on",is_default="true",composite="hji"
```

Comment: @RajMullapu `egrep` scans and either prints or does not print *whole lines*. You'd need to use something else to begin with or pipe the output to something else in order to trim the lines you match. Can you clarify how much you want to show? From `partition` to the closing `}`?

Comment: @Telemachus am expecting same output as i mentioned in the question starting with partition to composite

Comment: @RajMullapu In future questions, please try to explain more precisely what you want to extract. We don't know, for example, if there are any lines where `composite` is not the last item before a closing brace. In a case like that, would you still want to stop at `composite`? Or would you want to continue to `}`? We can't know if you don't say.

Comment: @Telemachus sry for the confusion yes we have to stop at composite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understood your file might have more lines you don't want to see, so i would use:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(partition.*\)}.*/\1/p' file
```

we use `-n p` to show only lines where we made substitution. The substitution part just gets the part of the line you need substituting the whole line with the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

If your version of grep supports Perl-style regular expressions, then I'd use this:

```
grep -oP '.*?,\K[^}]+' file
```

It removes everything up to the first comma (`\K` kills any previous output) and prints everything up to the `}`.

Alternatively, using awk:

```
awk -F'}' '{ sub(/[^,]+,/, ""); print $1 }' file
```

This sets the field separator to `}` so the part you're interested in is the first field. It then uses `sub` to remove the part up to the first comma.

For completeness, you could also use sed:

```
sed 's/[^,]*,\([^}]*\).*/\1/' file
```

This captures the part after the first `,` up to the `}` and replaces the content of the line with it.

Comment: Ooh, nifty, didn't know `grep` could do that.

Comment: Not every `grep` can.

Comment: Some can! In particular, GNU grep supports the `-P` switch (not sure if some others do as well).

Comment: Hmm, `info grep` on my box says "This is highly experimental and `grep -P' may warn of unimplemented features." GNU grep 2.12. Danger Will Robinson.

Comment: That message is pretty old and there's nothing particularly advanced about the features being used here.

Comment: ...then I guess your version of grep doesn't support it. The sed or awk options are much more likely to work on your platform.

Answer (score 3):

After the `grep` to pick out the lines you want, use `sed` to edit the lines:

```
sed 's/.*\(partition[^}]*\)} map.*/\1/'
```

This means: "whenever you see anything `.*`, followed by `partition` and
any number of non-`}`, then `} map` and anything else, grab the part
from `partition` up to but not including the brace `\(...\)` as group 1.
The replacement text is just group 1 `\1`.

Use a pipe `|` to connect the output of `egrep` to the input of `sed`:

```
egrep ... | sed ...
```

Comment: op can do everything in one sed, no need for pipes

Comment: @BigOldTree: Well, yes, but (a) that's how the OP put the question, and (b) it's easier to understand that way than by using sed's selection tools. If OP wants to delve deeper into what sed can do, that's up to them.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU  sed):

```
sed -r 's/(partition|is_active|state|is_default|composite)="[^"]*"/\n&\n/g;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*)\n[^\n]*/\1,/g;s/,$//' file
```

Treat the problem as if it were a "decomposed club sandwich". Identify the fillings, remove the bread and tidy up.